# How can I create a basis state of $n$ qubits in Q#?

Tags: quantum-state, programming, q#

I would like to create a set of basis qubits. For example if I have $n=2$ I should get 4 states being 01 10 11 00. Generalized for $2^n$. Is there a way to do this in Q#?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the "set of basis qubits"... Are you looking for this task: https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/Superposition/Tasks.qs#L123 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.preparation.prepareuniformsuperposition
Provides a nice operation to set register as LE and create the above script but a bit more efficiently without use of for loop.

Comment: It seems this has depreciated, it would be better to use ApplyToEach(H,register), where register is a pre determined

Answer (score 1):

To get a superposition of all the possible states, each qubit has an equal probability of being a 0/1.
So you apply a Hadamard gate to each qubit.

In Q# :

```
using(qubits = Qubit[N])
{
    for(q in qubits)
    {
        H(q);
    }
    // Now the qubits are in a superposition of all possible states.
}
```